# JSON only returning one record

Tags: jquery, json, url, format

There are hundreds of records when I do this but I can't add any other info:

function(data){

```
       $.each(data.products, function(i,item){   

         $("<img>").attr("src", item.imageUrl).appendTo("#pear");   

         if ( i == 100 ) return false;   

       });   

     });
```

But when I use this I only get one record:

```
    function(data){   

       $.each(data.products, function(i,item){   

         $("#images").html("<li><a href='"+item.pUrl+"'><img src='"+item.iUrl+"'></a>"+"<br>"+item.Name+"<br>"+"$"+item.salePrice+"</li>");  

         if ( i == 100 ) return false;   

       });   

     });
```

Can somene please explainto me what I am doing wrong -  very new to this.  Thanks

Comment: It's always good to start out explaining what your goal is and not just the problem

Answer (score 0):

Right now the bottom code replaces all code in `#images`

I think this would be better

```
function(data){   

   $.each(data.products, function(i,item){   

     $("#images").append("<li><a href='"+item.pUrl+"'><img src='"+item.iUrl+"'></a>"+"<br>"+item.Name+"<br>"+"$"+item.salePrice+"</li>");  

     if ( i == 100 ) return false;   

   });   

 });
```

Comment: AWESOME Thanks so much Nicklas! I tried to register to mark it as an answer but I keep getting a 404 page after I hit submit.